# Is there a way to make a long text fit in a small widget?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm making a notes app that contains notes with different sizes. Is there any way to set a max and min height to the note. I don't think the staggered view would help!

```
SliverGrid(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: notesview,
  ),
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      if (index < notes.length) {
        EdgeInsets.all(10);
        return notes[(notes.length - 1) - index];
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

Here's my note Custom widget :
it is generally a button to take the note to the edit page, and for the text whenever i paste a long one it over pass the tile limit, i don't if the problem is in the upper grid view or in the note itself.

````
class _CustomCardState extends State<CustomCard> {
  double font = 13;
  var now = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd' + ' At ' + 'H:m');
  String date;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    date = formatter.format(now);
    return new Card(
      color: widget._color,
      elevation: 2,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: RaisedButton(
        splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        elevation: 10,
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      EditNote(2, widget.index, widget._title)));
        },
        color: widget._color,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 5),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text("${widget._title}" + " => ${widget.index}",
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: font,
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5, right: 5),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(1, 0),
                    child: Text('$date',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          fontSize: font,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```
````

Comment: What is `notes`_? we don't know anything about it, it is just displaying a `Text` widget ?

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your widget which contains too long text with `SingleChildScrollView`

or

`String longText = "Longgggggggggggggggggggggggg text";`

```dart
                  Tooltip(// onPress to text it shows the full text.
                    message: longText,
                    child: Text(
                      longText.length < 20
                          ? longText
                          : longText.substring(0, 16) + '...',
                      // I divide my text in my case 16 length was enough.
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
```